# Debug/Emulate apps from Android Studio without adim rights

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a school laptop that I have Android Studio on. I can't install HTC drivers on it. I also can't get a virtual one, because I can't install Intel HAXM due to admin restrictions. I do have root on my phone. Please help!

Comment: Your best bet is ask your school for admin permissions for installation. Restriction like that is silly anyways. Or if you can, just doubleboot linux.

Comment: @poss How would dualbooting linux help? Like what would I be able to do then? Thanks

Comment: Well you don't need usb drivers on linux which is advantage. However question is if you can ever install linux and if your laptop is not protected against that.

Comment: Connect ADB over WiFi: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp

Comment: @poss I can access BIOS

Comment: Well in that case dualboot shouldnt be a problem. However try the solution over wifi above from Jared Rummler, seems to be the simplest - I didn't know about it so I didnt suggest it.

Comment: @poss it works with the usb wire now. I tried it before and it didn't work. So happy that it works now. Sucks to have a crappy school laptop that I can't do half the things on.